# Why CSS grid don't work even though my class tag was correct?

Tags: html, css

I want my h2 to appear on the right of the image, but it does not work when I use grid. Please let me know if you see something not right with my code. Thank you!

```css
body {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: "header nav" "berry menu" "footer footer";
        grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
        grid-template-rows: 200px 600px 100px;
    }
    
    .berry{
        grid-area: berry;
    }
    
    .menu{
        grid-area: menu;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
            <a>Shopping Basket</a>
    </nav>
        <header>
                <h1>Sally's Cheesecakes</h1>
        </header>

        <main>
            <div class="berry">
                <img src="images/berry_cheesecake.jpg" alt="berry_cheesecake" width="300" height="300">
            </div>
            <div class="menu"> 
                <h2>Made with fresh blueberries and farm cheese from New Zealand. <em>No added sugar</em> cake perfect for anyone </h2>
            </div>
        </main>
```

Comment: You need to adjust the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS you're styling the `body` element instead of `<main>`. Easiest mistakes may be most difficult to spot sometimes :)

Change

```css
body {
 ...
}
```

To

```css
main {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to redo the html structure in the same way as in my example. The `grid` rules will be assigned to the `main` tag.

```css
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header nav" "berry menu" "footer footer";
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
    grid-template-rows: 200px 600px 100px;
}

header {
    grid-area: header;
}

nav {
    grid-area: nav;
}

.berry{
    grid-area: berry;
}

.menu{
    grid-area: menu;
}

footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<main>

    <header>
            <h1>Sally's Cheesecakes</h1>
    </header>
    
    <nav>
        <a>Shopping Basket</a>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="berry">
            <img src="images/berry_cheesecake.jpg" alt="berry_cheesecake" width="300" height="300">
    </div>
    
    <div class="menu"> 
            <h2>Made with fresh blueberries and farm cheese from New Zealand. <em>No added sugar</em> cake perfect for anyone </h2>
    </div>
        
    <footer>
          footer
    </footer>
    
</main>
```